# I am using encrypt: 5.0.1, now what type of encryption algorithms does my app implement?

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect, publish

I am using encrypt: ^5.0.1 and https calls over server, now what type of encryption algorithms does my app implement? When I am publishing app to AppStore they were asking below questions.  Please see the piece of code that I use encrypt plugin for

```
String sha256String = CryptHelper.getSha256String(json.encode(body));
String encryptedBody = CryptHelper.getEncryptedBase64String(json.encode(body));
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Authorization': sha256String,
};
```

1. What type of encryption algorithms does your app implement?

   - 1 Encryption algorithms that are proprietary or not accepted as standard by international standard bodies (IEEE, IETF, ITU, etc.)
   - 2 Standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple's operating system
   - 3 Both algorithms mentioned above
   - 4 None of the algorithms mentioned above.
     I have selected 2nd answer and There was again another dialog where they are asking
2. Is your app going to be available for distribution in France?

   - 1  Yes
   - 2  No

and I answered NO as my app was not going to available in France. Now my question is, did I           selected correct option in first form??